# can we get a call back by using mailto function in php to hide the button and check mail has been sent?

Tags: php, html, email, mailto

can we get a call back by using mailto function in php to hide the button and check mail has been sent??

My email button
This mailto function opens up native mailbox, so is there any way to receive call back from it?
  I need to hide this link after sending mail..

Comment: <a href="mailto:qaz@yopmail.com">My email button</a>

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: No.  There isn't even a way to determine if the user's workstation can even *use* a `mailto:` link.  That is, if it even *has* a native mail client.  If you want to control the sending of messages, do it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get a response from the opened mailbox to see if they've actually sent the e-mail or not.